# Pivot Table without using aggregate function using oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, pivot, unpivot

I have table1 with following structure

```
          type month1 month2 month3 month4
           A     20    30      40    5
           B     10    30      50    7
           C     13    30      80    8
```

I am trying to get below output using table1

```
          month    A   B   C
          month1  20   10  13
          month2  30   30  30
          month3  40   50  80
          month4  5    7   8
```

In general its sql to get every column as row. No aggregation is needed here.

I have written following sql

```
             select decode (TYPE,'A',month1,null) A,
             decode (TYPE,'B',month1,null) B,
             decode (TYPE,'C',month1,null) C
             from table1
```

But its giving null values the obvious reason is I added null in decode statement.
I did try to give month values in decode but it is not working as one decode will create one row.
Can someone please suggest me better approach here ?

Comment: Please tag with the version of Oracle you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Though decode will be better, but you can also use UNION to achieve the same results.

```
Select 'month1' as month
, sum(case when type = 'A' then month1 else null end) as A
, sum(case when type = 'B' then month1 else null end) as B
, sum(case when type = 'C' then month1 else null end) as C
from table1
group by 'month1'

UNION ALL

Select 'month2' as month
, sum(case when type = 'A' then month2 else null end) as A
, sum(case when type = 'B' then month2 else null end) as B
, sum(case when type = 'C' then month2 else null end) as C
from table1
group by 'month2'

UNION ALL

Select 'month3' as month
, sum(case when type = 'A' then month3 else null end) as A
, sum(case when type = 'B' then month3 else null end) as B
, sum(case when type = 'C' then month3 else null end) as C
from table1
group by 'month3'

UNION ALL

Select 'month4' as month
, sum(case when type = 'A' then month4 else null end) as A
, sum(case when type = 'B' then month4 else null end) as B
, sum(case when type = 'C' then month4 else null end) as C
from table1
group by 'month4'
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/13cbae/3)

Comment: Thank you for your view . Suppose if number of month goes to 100 then this query will be too long. It will be very helpful if query can be generalize

Answer (score 0):

You can first apply `unpivot` in the subquery and `decode` with group by `month` as :

```
select month, max(decode(type,'A',value)) as "A",
              max(decode(type,'B',value)) as "B",
              max(decode(type,'C',value)) as "C"
  from
  (
    with t ( type, month1, month2, month3, month4 ) as
    (
     select 'A',20,30,40,5 from dual union all
     select 'B',10,30,50,7 from dual union all
     select 'C',13,30,80,8 from dual
    )    
    select type, month, value 
      from
         ( Select *
             From t ) p
    unpivot  
       (value for month in
          ( month1, month2, month3, month4)  
    ) unpvt
   ) 
group by month
order by month;

MONTH   A   B   C
------  --  --  --
MONTH1  20  10  13
MONTH2  30  30  30
MONTH3  40  50  80
MONTH4  5   7   8
```

[***Rextester Demo***](https://rextester.com/DFE74651)

Comment: I appreciate your view. Statements like `select 'A',20,30,40,5 from dual union all` with hardcoded values means I need to change query when there is some change in data.

Comment: @pravinkottawar thank you. Perhaps, to store those types as dates or versus dates and as a result to get statistics may be a better choice.